# page rank algorithm iterative conversion

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, page-rank

I am trying to implement a pagerank algorithm using the formula: 
p = the probability vector og getting on a page
Pbeginning = matrix(n,1) full with 1/n

S = the matrix with damping factor of the network.

now I have to do iterative till they converge:

for i in range(10):
     p = S * p

Howerver how do I know when they converge?
Some people suggest abs(pn-1 - pn) and keep iterating till this is small, others suggest just iterating 20 times or so.

Answer (score 1):

$20$ iterations need not work for some graph network.

According to ["The PageRank Citation Ranking - Bringing Order to the Web" by Page, Brin, Motwani, Winograd](https://web.archive.org/web/20220331094511/http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/422/1/1999-66.pdf), Section $2.6$, we set a small positive number $\delta$, which is an error tolerance, we terminate when $$\|R_{i+1}-R_i\|_1 \le \delta.$$

We can also see other norms are used as well on Wikipedia page.

Remark: Neither proved convergence has attained, but it is a common practice.